# JSON is undefined in IE 11

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-11

We have a web application which is used from Windows 7 with IE 11. For all of them, but one person, it works normally.

1 user get's the error message

```
"JSON" is undefined
```

This happens in the line where we run

```
JSON.parse(....)
```

The document has the normal doctype header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

And the website shouldn't be rendered in IE's compatibility mode (at least according to the screenshots provided by the user)

The only way we could reproduce it was, activating the compatibility mode. And as I said it works for >20 other users.

So is there a way to check if the application is executed in compatibility mode? Or maybe there is another reason how JSON could be undefined?

Comment: If it's only failing for one user, it's probably some customization he has that's breaking it.

Comment: If this is happening only for one user then you have to check if for that particular user server is not returning the json string.

Comment: @Barmar Those users are from the same company and centrally managed. Although this user is in a different office. Any idea what kind of customisation this could be?

Comment: No idea. But there must be something different in his configuration

Comment: @Sandeeproop the JSON string is stored in `localStorage` in this case. And the fact that the JSON-object doesn't exist has nothing to do with the string passed to JSON.parse

Comment: Can you try this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
document.documentMode
```

to check the compatibility mode.